# Getting div id by GET in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Ciao

I need to create a dynamic form based on user selections.

I.e. in the first form field I select `"John Smith"`, this will populate (through an external php/mysql file ) the second select field `"Artist, Carpenter, Other"`, if I choose Artist I populate the third select field with `"Singer, Painter, Sculptor"` and so on

Giving my incompetence on javascript, I spent the morning googling for scripts and I found a [cool tutorial here](http://www.satya-weblog.com/2007/04/dynamically-populate-select-list-by.html)

It works, it's clean, but it updates only the div with id `txtResult`, which is **statically** included in the js file (see lines 19 and 31 of ajax_req.js). I thought I could pass the id name by GET, but I don't know how to make the script recognize the variable.

This is the code:

```
function stateChanged()  
{  
   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")  
   {  
           document.getElementById("txtResult").innerHTML= xmlHttp.responseText;  
   }  

}
```

I had in mind to pass by GET the id name and have something like this:

```
function stateChanged()  
{  
   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")  
   {  
           document.getElementById("GET[idName]").innerHTML= xmlHttp.responseText;  
   }  

}
```

Can you please help me? I could change script too if you happen to know something better

Ciao and thank you,

Ed

Comment: is `idName` a variable which has the `id` of your output `div`? If yes, just try `document.getElementById(idName)...`.

Comment: Man the bracketing it almost causing me anxiety since the IDEs I use always pull up the first up to the function definition. Though I do prefer this way in other languages.

Comment: Why not just pass the idname as parameter? function stateChanged(idName)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `select` pass id of your `element`,

```
<select name="country" onchange="htmlData('city.php', 'ch='+this.value, 'your_element_id')" />
```

In `htmlData()`

```
function htmlData(url, qStr, id) { // get id as well that is 'your_element_id'

   //You can do line 43 in `ajax_req.js` as,

   xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                                    stateChanged(id);
                                }
}
```

In `stateChanged()`

```
function stateChanged(id)  
{  
   if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete")  
   {  
           document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= xmlHttp.responseText;  
   }  
   else {  
           //alert(xmlHttp.status);  
   }  
}
```

Then you can do in line 31 as,

```
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML="";
```

Comment: Ok, everything works fine. I find it easier to implement Ajith's code, even if I'm sure Dalım's code would work just fine. Again, thank you very much for your efforts, beer is on me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the HTML ...

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $.get('x.php?f_name=get_names',function(data){
                $("#select_name").html(data);
                $.get("x.php?f_name=get_jobs&s_name="+$("#select_name").val(),function(data){
                    $("#select_job").show();
                    $("#select_job").html(data);
                })
            });


            $("#select_name").change(function(){
                $.get("x.php?f_name=get_jobs&s_name="+$("#select_name").val(),function(data){
                    $("#select_job").html(data);
                })

            });





        })

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <select name="name" id="select_name">

        </select>

        <select name="job" id="select_job"></select>
    </body>
    </html>
```

, and This is PHP side (called x.php in the code)

```
    <?php
        $names = array("A","B","C");
        $jobs  = array(array("Job_1","Job_2") ,array("Job_1"), array("Job_1","Job_2","Job_3"));
        GLOBAL $names;
        GLOBAL $jobs;


        switch ($_GET['f_name']) {
            case 'get_names':
                get_names($names);
                break;
            case 'get_jobs':
                get_jobs($jobs,$_GET['s_name']);
                break;
            default:
                # code...
                break;
        }





        function get_names($names){
            foreach ($names as $key=>$value) {
                echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
            }
            return false;
        }
        function get_jobs($jobs,$s_name){
            foreach ($jobs[$s_name] as $key => $value) {
                echo "<option value='$key'>$value</option>";
            }
            return false;
        }



    ?>
```

You can create your own array such as $names and $jobs, and add some case to switch to get more complex systems...

Have a nice day.

Comment: Ok, I'm working on it, I'll reply soon as soon I've done the testing. In the meantime, thank you everybody, feel free to put a beer on my tab